Did the Roman Empire lie?
Some modern countries, including the US, Russia, and the UK in particular are blamed (by the other side, where Russia is confronted to US+UK) to be particularly lying in politics, using their powerful propaganda.
In comparison with modern countries, can Roman Empire by called a political liar?
AFAIK, Roman Empire openly declared its bloody plan to seize the world, for their own benefits. So, it could probably called more honest than modern countries from the above list. Is it so?
Please, describe the most significant aspects in which Roman Empire was lying and in which not (in comparison to modern propaganda).

To whom do you think the Romans would have been lying? To their own people or to the barbarians?

The question is more about lying to barbarians. But I am also interested of how much Roman authorities did lie to their own people. @SteveBird

This does remind me of the old joke "How can you tell when a politician is lying? Their mouth is open...". Lies have been a part of politics since politics became a thing.

Recommend closure since there is no way to define the "best" example, and therefore no Authoritative answer

Two examples from the Eastern Roman Empire are the end of the Nika revolt in 532 and the assassination attempt on the Bulgarian Khan Krum in 813. Zeno's treatment of Basiliscus and his family in 476 is an example of keeping a promise in letter but not in spirit.

Yes. All states lie.
The first example that comes to mind.

Meanwhile, of course, Rome’s victory over Philip V in 197 had left Rome, at least for the moment, as the dominant power in mainland Greece and over much of the Aegean, with the victorious Titus Quinctius Flamininus spending the period from 197 to 194 settling affairs in Greece, declaring the Greeks ‘free’ at the Isthmian Games in 196 (but of course the Roman understanding here is ‘free, but under Roman protection’ which is not the Greek understanding of ‘free’ – libertas and eleutheria (ἐλευθερία) are not quite perfect synonyms). ACOUP

The question is predicated on the assumption  that "telling the truth" and "lying" define the two possible states for each action. This is a woefully inadequate model for international relations. (quite frankly it is a lousy model for nearly any relationship, or any communications analysis; I shudder to think of the fights if I evaluated every one of my life partner's statements as either "true" or "false")
I would at a minimum, shift to modern communications theory, and look at each statement from the standpoint of the sender's bias, the sender's intent, the sender's information/perception, the receivers bias, intent, perception, plus distorting elements of the communications channels.
Beyond all that, manipulating the truth is not only normal but necessary.  Part of the process of state formation is establishing legitimacy, normally through some form of a state mythology.  Was Rome ruled by the Senate and People of Rome? (not in any way that would qualify as "true"; the Senate's decrees had no legal force, and the people's vote was not relevant)  It was a useful mythology to bind people into a state.
States must lie in diplomacy; negotiation is an exercise in creative truth telling and constraining diplomatic communications to "truth" would put the unconstrained state at a significant advantage.  (I invite examples; none are coming to mind that are easily captured in a paragraph with sources.)
All warfare is based on deception The Art of War or Military Deception; again a full treatment would require far more discussion that is appropriate within H:SE
When Caligula "Conquered the sea" was that an act of madness, or a symbolic act?  Or when he threatened to name his horse a consul? Was that an act of insanity, or was it a calculated insult to show the Senate just how irrelevant they were? (by that point there was no functional difference between the Emperor of Rome and the State of Rome.)
Almost all pre-modern states asserted their right to rule the world.  (Can anyone name when the first example of an intentional international strategy of cooperation took place? Is Kissinger the first to set this as a strategic aim?  Arguably the Conference of Vienna, but even there, it was merely a strategy in a struggle for dominance) In an economy based on land and specie it is a rational strategy.  (Most states have no hope of fulfilling that intent), but if your economy is based on direct exploitation, of either gold or your neighbors, conquering the world is the only way to be both rich and safe. (Chinngis Khan was the "Khan of the four oceans"; the modern concept of the Divine Right of Kings, the whole concept of theocracy, etc.)
I've been tempted to do as the question asks and compare to modern propaganda, but that would strain the scope of history, and I believe that the question of the truth of propaganda has been discussed elsewhere.  It simply isn't useful to discuss propaganda as "true" or "false".

In the 20th century, the English term propaganda was often associated with a manipulative approach, but historically, propaganda had been a neutral descriptive term of any material that promotes certain opinions or ideologies. Wikipedia:Propaganda

Expanding the question to include this topic would further muddle the issues.
I'm confident that others can provide innumerable examples.
